# vconsole setup: unable to open the include file euro2

Tags: shell, arch-linux, syntax

I formatted my Arch Linux and reinstalled for some reasons I wanted to start over

After installation, a very strange error appeared.

In the chrooted installation I created the file `/etc/vconsole.conf` and wrote:

```
KEYMAP=pt-latin1
```

And then I saved it and that was fine. But later, with the system started, it continues with the US keymap and not with pt-latin1

And I read some threads and saw the command

```
usr/lib/systemd/systemd-vconsole-setup
```

And it gave the following output:

```
unable to open the include file euro2 
syntax error, unexpected ERROR 
/usr/bin/loadkeys failed with exit status 1.
```

And it never happened to me. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by editing pt-latin1 to pt-latin9